# Parse HTML in Silverlight for Windows Embedded

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

I'm trying to show some files (html format) in a page of my application.

If anyone has an example on how to do this, even remotely related, I would be grateful.

So far I haven't found anything in my searches so I welcome any links, suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the OS version you are using and its configuration, but you should be able to use the HTML/DHTML APIs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee492824(v=winembedded.60).aspx
If you need to rendere some HTML (and not just parse it) you may host the browser control inside your application and define a Win32 XAML controls that will contain it. This control doesn't support all the XAML features (rotation, transparency etc.) but can be placed inside a layout and controlled by your app.

Comment: Forgot to add that the Windows Embedded Compact 7 browser does what I describe and, even if it's a bit complex to study IIRC you should be able to find it inside the shared source tree, it may be a good sample of what you can/should do. To have the code you need to install a licensed copy of platform builder.